# In the ring of even integers, why is $2$ neither singular nor regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

From what I understand, elements of a ring which are not regular are singular. So how is it possible that in the set of even numbers, $2$ is neither regular nor singular?

Edit: To clarify, an element $x$ of a ring is called regular if it has an inverse. Otherwise, it is said to be singular.

Comment: What are regular and singular elements of a ring?  Are you just talking about zero divisors?

Comment: Perhaps you should include what definition of regular and singular you are working with, and how you came to the conclusion (or where you saw) that $2$ is neither.

Comment: Might also help to indicate the sense in which you want the set of even integers to be a ring.  (the usual multiplication won't work as there is no multiplicative unit in the set).

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reference on this topic: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=sSRgg0gM3XQC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=singular+ring+element&source=bl&ots=NTDzn0fVtR&sig=KcY4RoMOYNEIjLI98fAnlZBExW4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTt6XAppTZAhVQj1kKHeT3AywQ6AEIWzAH#v=onepage&q=singular%20ring%20element&f=false)

This book talks about regular and singular ring elements, and it says, "An element which is not regular is called singular". However, this author makes it clear from the start that these definitions apply to "An element $a$ in a ring $R$ with multiplicative identity".

The set of even numbers, by which I presume you mean $2\Bbb Z$, is not a ring with identity, so we're not in the right context to talk about regular vs. singular elements, at least according to the above source.